# Subtext for C# label

Tags: c#

I need to put some subtext in a Winforms C# labels .Text property.  Is there any easy way to do this without writng my own control?

This would be the example in HTML

```
<sub>1a</sub>
```

Thanks,
Paul.

Comment: Do you mean some additional label text that would sit under the main label? I think the answer is no regardless and I'd either make a user control with two label controls (one below the other with a smaller text size) or just place the subtext when and where I needed it.

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing that, but that technique becomes a pain when I need to...

1) The subtext needs to be in the middle of a large bit of text,
2) The text needs to resize/anchor with the form,
3) Changes in DPI need to work correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a link to an already-written control that does exactly this:

http://www.freshnova.com/C-Tutorials/superscript-subscript-label.html

**Update**:  you can also just use a RichTextBox (with BorderStyle none, BackColor control, and ReadOnly true).  The RichTextBox's `SelectionCharOffset` lets you specify the height of text above or below the baseline in pixels, and then set its `SelectedText` property after each setting of `SelectionCharOffset` to mix-and-match text of different positions in the one box.

Comment: Chees for the link.  I used Reflector to see how it was done.

Comment: The page is no longer there, but the waybackmachine has a copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20100805065819/http://www.freshnova.com/C-Tutorials/superscript-subscript-label.html

Answer (score 3):

No, you'll have to write your own control.

Just create a new user control within your project and add two labels to it. Then add some server side properties for getting/setting the label values.

Then just add the user control to the page.

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing that, but that technique becomes a pain when I need to... 

1) The subtext needs to be in the middle of a large bit of text, 
2) The text needs to resize/anchor with the form, 
3) Changes in DPI need to work correctly.

Comment: You could add properties to the custom control and override Control default behaviour to get the functionality you want, e.g. subtext font changes and anchoring

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's bothered, I ended up writing my own...

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XXX.UI.Custom
{
/// <summary>
/// A label which is capable of subscript.
/// 
/// Version: 1.
/// Author: XXX.
/// Date: 15/10/2009.
/// Changes: Initial version.
/// </summary>
public class SubscriptLabel : Label
{
    #region Vars

    // Vars.
    private char _subMark = '`';
    private SolidBrush _brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    private StringFormat _stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the subscript marker.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The subscript marker.</value>
    [Description("Marker for start/end of subscript text."),
    Category("Appearance"),
    Browsable(true)]
    public char SubscriptMarker
    {
        get
        {
            return _subMark;
        }
        set
        {
            _subMark = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    #region Public

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SubscriptLabel"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public SubscriptLabel()
    {
        // Setup text mode.
        _stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        _stringFormat.HotkeyPrefix = HotkeyPrefix.Show;
        _stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        _stringFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;
        _stringFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces | StringFormatFlags.DisplayFormatControl
            | StringFormatFlags.NoClip | StringFormatFlags.NoFontFallback
            | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private

    /// <summary>
    /// Measures the Y DSW.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphics">The graphics.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    /// <param name="font">The font.</param>
    /// <returns>The size.</returns>
    private SizeF MeasureDSW(Graphics graphics, string text,
        Font font)
    {
        // Init.
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;

        // Vars.
        StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        SizeF size = new SizeF();

        // Init.
        stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        stringFormat.HotkeyPrefix = HotkeyPrefix.Show;
        stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
        stringFormat.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;
        stringFormat.HotkeyPrefix = HotkeyPrefix.None;
        stringFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces | StringFormatFlags.NoClip
            | StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;

        // The string size.
        size = graphics.MeasureString(text, Font,
            Width, stringFormat);

        // Init.
        graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;

        return size;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The pain method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="T:System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs"/> that contains the event data.</param>
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ensure that we have some text to draw.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            // Init.
            float currentX = 0f;
            float currentY = 0f;
            string[] splittedText = Text.Split(SubscriptMarker);

            // Setup graphics.
            e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.Default;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.Default;
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SystemDefault;
            e.Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;

            // Loop around the splitted text.
            for (int i = 0; i < splittedText.Length; i++)
            {
                // Vars.
                int drawSubscript = i % 2;

                // Are we to draw the subscript?
                if (drawSubscript > 0)
                {
                    DrawText(e.Graphics, ref currentX,
                        ref currentY, splittedText,
                        i, true);
                }
                else // Don't draw the subscript?
                {
                    DrawText(e.Graphics, ref currentX,
                        ref currentY, splittedText,
                        i, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Draws the text onto the control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="graphics">The graphics.</param>
    /// <param name="currentX">The current X.</param>
    /// <param name="currentY">The current Y.</param>
    /// <param name="splittedText">The splitted text.</param>
    /// <param name="i">The current text array position.</param>
    /// <param name="isSubScript">if set to <c>true</c> [is sub script].</param>
    private void DrawText(Graphics graphics, ref float currentX,
        ref float currentY, string[] splittedText,
        int i, bool isSubScript)
    {
        // Vars.
        string[] words = splittedText[i].Split(' ');

        // Loop around all the words.
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            // Vars.
            string newWord = word + " ";
            float nextPosWord = MeasureDSW(graphics, newWord,
                Font).Width;

            // Are we on the final element?
            if (word == words[words.Length-1] && !isSubScript)
            {
                // Remove the space.
                newWord = newWord.Trim();

                // Re-measure to remove the space.
                nextPosWord = MeasureDSW(graphics, newWord,
                    Font).Width;
            }

            // Are we over the end of the label?
            if ((currentX + nextPosWord) > Width)
            {
                // Add the Y coords.
                currentY += MeasureDSW(graphics, newWord,
                    Font).Height;

                // Reset the X coords.
                currentX = 0;
            }

            // Vars.
            float newCurrentY = currentY;

            // Is this for the sub script characters?
            if (isSubScript)
            {
                // Add offsets.
                newCurrentY += 5 * graphics.DpiY / 96; ;
            }

            // Draw onto the control.
            graphics.DrawString(newWord, Font,
                _brush, currentX, 
                newCurrentY);

            // Add the size onto the X coords.
            currentX += nextPosWord;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somebody has mentioned using "character map" tool in this [post](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/75618-superscript-text-in-names-of-lables-and-buttons/page__view__findpost__p__484817). Quickest if your labels have static text.

> Goto Start->Programs->Accessories->System tools->Character Map. 
>   Now select this Character ² from the Characters listed. Click "Select", 
>   Click "Copy",  Then try to change the text of any control by pasting
>   this Character. It should work.

```
Button1.Text = "mm²"
```